# Mesh Network using C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a mesh network of size 3*3 in C language for simulation purpose (using `CSIM`).

```
X --- X --- X
|     |     |
X --- X --- X
|     |     |
X --- X --- X
```

The following overlapping loop is supposed to simulate the link between nodes however does not really simulate the mesh topology since it counts the diagonal links as well. I apologize for this question but I really don't know how to modify it to represent a mesh network. Any hint is appreciated.

```
int net[5][5];
    for(i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5;j++)
        {
            net[i][j] = link;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any relation between the image, the code and the question. Please, get out of your context and try to describe it from outside.

Comment: this code will initialize the matrix net with the same value link... what are you tryng to do?

Comment: You probably want to connect nodes where `i` is the same or where `j` is the same. Like (0,0) to (0,1) to (0,2), but not (0,0) to (2, 1).

Comment: What you are describing in a two-dimensional array.  If you want a mesh, then you need to implement a linked list.

Comment: What is `net`? What is `link`? Why is `net` a 5x5 array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about a 5x5 matrix and complained about the diagonals filled in, I assume that you want a matrix where the entries are either nodes (where you have "X"), links (where you have either "---" or "|"), or where you have nothing. I'm not sure if using a 5x5 array for a 3x3 mesh is a good idea, but if you really want that you could do something like the following:

First create an enumerated type with 3 elements like thus:

```
typedef enum {NODE,LINK,EMPTY} slot;
```

Then declare `net` as a 5x5 array of type `slot` and populate it in 2 nested loops depending on whether nodes and links or links and empties are alternating. The following code illustrates how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {NODE,LINK,EMPTY} slot;

int main(void){
    int i,j;
    slot net[5][5];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i+=2){
       for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            net[i][j] = j%2 == 0? NODE : LINK;
       }
    }


    for(i = 1; i < 5; i+=2){
       for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
           net[i][j] = j%2 == 0? LINK : EMPTY;
       }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
           switch(net[i][j]){
              case NODE:
                  printf("X");
                  break;
              case LINK:
                  printf("+");
                  break;
              default:
                  printf(" ");
                  break;
           }
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
X+X+X
+ + +
X+X+X
+ + +
X+X+X
```